# Why is my SoapUI user interface full of odd fonts (and is completely unusable)?

Tags: fonts, user-interface

After multiple re-installs and using different versions, I suspect there could be some kind of corruption in the font file used by SoapUI but I am unable to determine which font to reinstall.

The versions I have installed are 5.4.0 and 5.5.0.

[image: See screenshot [here][1].]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, a font file was corrupted and by following instructions (and downloading the full default fonts pack) from https://www.w7df.com/ I was able to resolve the issue.